# SP13: Sending Email after a Field Change

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, custom-list

I think this can be done but not sure. I have list full of names that are assigned tasks.  Each item has a task already assigned but at time there could be a chance that the name of the assigned person will change.  If it changes I want an email to go only to the new person responsible of that task and no one else on the list.  I can't figure out where to start.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've posted a question on this myself, I subsequently posted a detailed answer that you'll [find here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189787/send-alert-to-a-user-when-the-assigned-to-is-changed-in-a-list-item).

In a nutshell, you can use Sharepoint Designer to write a simple workflow using an IF statement.  What you need is to write the value (name) of the current `Assigned To` to a simple text field, let's call it `AssignedToTextField`.

A workflow similar to this would do it:

IF `AssignedTo` not equal to `AssignedToTextField`, send email to `AssignedTo`, 
then SET `AssignedToTextField` to `AssignedTo` value.

The 'SET' part of the workflow is responsible for ensuring the email notification can work more than once.  It checks to see if the name is different between the two fields, if it is different it sends an email "Hey, you have a new task" then the SET command copies the name of the person emailed and pastes it in the `AssignedToTextField`.  Set the workflow to run when an item is modified.

21/06/2018 - Additional note in response to comment:

1. Following the email being sent the workflow updates `Text Name` to make it match with `Assigned To`.  For my purposes, I wanted the `Assigned To` to be emailed upon item creation & when modified.  If this isn't the behaviour you want for triggering your email, you'd need to change the workflow start options - choose only 'when item changed', deselect 'when item created'.

[image: screenshot of workflow]

2. "...field copying over the AD name..."

I've made a mistake in the field type definition.  The `Assigned To` and `Text Field` should both be set to **Display Names, Semicolon Delimited** and not String.

I checked this by using the "Log" command in the workflow, to log the value that Sharepoint finds in the `Assigned To` field.

[image: Assigned To field type]

The item workflow history shows the values (the LOG command causes this info to be logged here):

So when the field types do not match, different values are returned.  Sorry about misadvising you.  I'll update my linked Answer.

[image: Difference in values due to field types not matching]

Comment: ! Thank you for the details.  I tried but the Assigned Text Field sends an email at the initial submission and I made sure the workflow settings were correct. Shouldn't only be sent when the fields not equal not when the workflow initially puts the assigned name into the task field?  Also, the field is also copying over the AD name along with the Displayed Name of the assigned person into the Text field.

Comment: Hi, I've added a picture to my answer - I have two fields here.  Initially the value in 'Text Name' is blank, so does not match the name in 'Assigned To' -> therefore send email to Assigned To.

Comment: One more thing I should mention.  In my linked Answer - I have updated points 10 & 13, so that the correct field type is now indicated.  Point 10 needs an 'email' field type.  Point 13 needs a 'Display Name, Semicolon Delimited' field type.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the built-in "Task" list type, it has the ability to "Send Email When Ownership is Assigned". And it emails whoever is in the "Assigned To" box. I don't believe it emails the "old" person when an update occurs if the assignment changes as part of the update.

If you're not using the built-in Task list, you'll need to create a workflow that checks the field containing the person and send them an email that way. Set it to run on add and update.