# Simple Workflow For Automated Task Management

Tags: workflow, task-list

Looking for some help to create a simple task workflow in Sharepoint 2016. Please look at the following steps:

This should be the workflow step by step:

1. User receives automatic email to begin first task of the day.
2. User completes task and then marks as complete and submits.
3. The next user gets the next task via email, and then marks as complete
4. This cascade continues until the tasks are all complete
5. Data is sent out in summary to all users.

Please let me know if you need more info!

Thanks to anyone who helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use an out-of-the-box Task List.  Every time the 'Assigned To' changes the user should be notified by email.

On point 5, just include a link to the task item in the email and the user can see all the data.

For more info please see [this link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/243648/sp13-sending-email-after-a-field-change/243678#243678) to an Answer and a separate Question I posted which covers emailing a user when a task is assigned to them.