# Sending email through SharePoint designer 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, 2016, project-server

I'm trying to send an email to a person who submitted a new project request as part of a SharePoint Designer workflow using a project detail page (PDP) in Microsoft Project Server 2016.

Email recipient will be different in each time since different people can submit a project request and the workflow needs to determine the email address of the person who submitted the request and emails the person.

I cannot find a way to set up the email recipient in SharePoint Designer 2013 to accomplish this task.

I found the following URL on this subject http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-send-an-email-using-workflow-when-items-are-created-or-updated-in-sharepoint/.

However, the step 6 on this page does not provide enough details on how to set up the recipient email automatically in the SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow.

Is this possible? Can you please help? Thank you,

Comment: You can keep a list field in which you can keep a record of the users who are submitting the request. And then can read that list column item field to send an email to the specific user.

Comment: I need to dynamically determine the project server user's email address. This user would be completing and submitting a project detail page (form) in Project Server 2016 in order to get approval from his supervisor. Depending on the user, a different supervisor may need to approve the project request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok where are you stuck in step 6? You need to press the book icon to the far right of the "To"-field. This will open the window displayed. There you quite literally press the fields marked in the picture and you're good.

Comment: Please see my response to Niranjan Kulkarni above. Essentially, I do not see the "User who created current item" option in the "Select Users" dialog box because "Current Item" is not available for me to select. I wonder if this is due to I'm using Project Server 2016 workflow type instead of regular SharePoint workflow type.

Comment: Ok do you by any change use Site workflows? If that's the case you will not see the "Current item" as an option for obivious reasons (Since the workflow isn't tied to a list but rather a site and subsequently not tied to an item). I have zero experience with Project server workflows (Didn't even know they existed) so if that's hte case I'm not able to help you out.

Comment: Yes, I'm using a Project Server Site Workflow to create the project approval process. I'm new to project server workflows but I think they are some variations of SharePoint 2013/2016 workflows. Thank you for your clarification of unavailability of "Current Item" in "Site Workflows". You already helped.

Comment: Glad to help even if i was just a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar kind of issue when I started grappling with Sharepoint Designer Workflows.  You should find it useful, it has loads of pictures and step-by-step instructions.  I posted the question and an [answer here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189787/send-alert-to-a-user-when-the-assigned-to-is-changed-in-a-list-item).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree with you working with SharePoint Designer workflows seems to be complicated. The product shows its age (it is not being developed anymore). Since I'm trying to use Site Workflows, some of the provided instructions are not applicable to my use case. Thank again!