# SharePoint Desiger 2013-Workflow with Impersonation Step Does Not Notify the Right Person if a Task is Reassigned

Tags: sharepoint-designer-workflow

Workflow Details:

- Impersonation step is set at the beginning of the workflow--grants
  Contribute (No Delete) item permissions to Supervisor 1 which is
  manually entered by the requester in a list column.

  - Task Process: Starts on current item with Supervisor 1

Task Outcomes:

- Acknowledge Receipt
- Withdraw Request

General Settings: Reassignment

Issue: When a the task is reassigned, the workflow owners get notified as opposed to the new approver. The workflow does not show any errors, remains in progress, and the task list does generate the task for the new approver, except there's no email notification.  Is this due to permissions? And how do we remedy that?

Comment: I think some extra details would be useful.  Are you using an Out of the Box (OOTB) workflow e.g. reusable workflow?  If it is an OOTB workflow I would have expected it to notify the new approver.  If the workflow is a custom-made one, then you could add a few lines to the workflow (using SPD), added code to notify the new approver by email.

Comment: Custom Workflow, not reusable. The workflow has Reassignment turned on, just in case an incorrect supervisor is entered. Reassignment from Supv1 to Supv2  could happen multiple times (Supv2 to 3....) within the same task process.

Comment: It that case, I think you need to add a little bit to the workflow.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar kind of question to yours [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/189787/send-alert-to-a-user-when-the-assigned-to-is-changed-in-a-list-item).

You'll need to create a text field (I've called mine Text Name) and make your workflow SET the value of the text field to Current Item:Assigned To.

If the task is reassigned, Sharepoint will see that the 'Assigned To' is different to the Text Name field.  Aha!  The Assigned To is different, therefore send an email to the new Assigned To.

Every time a task is reassigned, the workflow needs to update the Text Name field - so that Sharepoint has something to compare against if the Assigned To changes again.

[image: assigned to not equals assigned to value]

Comment: I'll go ahead and try your brilliant idea. I'm hoping the impersonation step will not block the new Assign To. Not sure if reassignment comes packed with the same permission as the previous approver. I'll let you know once I test. Again thank you!

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?